# How to override/alias named route helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my application, all of my models depend on a main model. That's why all of my routes are nested inside this main route. My route.rb look like that :

```
resources :main_model do
  resources :model_1
  resources :model_2
  resources :model_3 do
    resources :model_4
  end
end
```

So, any of my named route helpers repeat the same beginning with the same object (wich is in session). I call my paths like that :

```
new_main_model_model_1_path(session[:main_model])
edit_main_model_model_3_model_4_path(session[:main_model], @model_3, @model_4)
```

But i am tired of repeating myself in each link so I want to be able to call my routes like that :

```
new_model_1_path()
edit_model_3_model_4_path(@model_3, @model_4)
```

I could write alias methods...

```
def new_model_1_path(model_1)
  new_main_model_model_1_path(session[:main_model], model_1)
end
```

...but it would not be serious. Is there a way to do it cleanly ? Perhaps by overridding the named route generator ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have reference to your main model in the session you don't actually the routes to identify it. You already know where to find it. So, for the purposes of routing, there's no need to nest the resources at all.

You could use `scope` instead, if you still want to prefix your routes:

```
scope "main_model" do
  resources :model_1
  resources :model_2
  resources :model_3 do
    resources: :model_4
  end
end
```

That will give you the helper methods you want that don't require you to pass the redundant reference to `main_model`.

Or just don't nest them.

Comment: It's a good aproach but I want to have explicit URL with my main object inside. So I can write a scope like that : `scope '(:main_model)', :main_model => /.+/ do`. But it will be necessary to specify the main_model in each helper like that : `new_model_1_path(session[:main_model], model_1)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. You can still prefix the route when using `scope` to make the model 'explicit' but you won't have to pass it to your helper since you're not actually using it as a resource.